# vibe.d application code porting trouble

Tags: d, dmd, vibed

#### Abstract

[Vibe.d](http://vibed.org) has undergone a lot of breaking changes. The same applied to the compiler.

I'm trying to get running a piece of code written back in 2012 with an earlier release of the [dmd](/questions/tagged/dmd) compiler and [vibe](/questions/tagged/vibe).

My porting effort is in vain and I am requesting help to settle that.

---

#### What I've done so far

The depracation of `vibe.core.signal` module is such a major event among others.

So in a module, I've replaced

```
import vibe.core.signal;

    ...

private:
    Signal m_signal;
    
    ...
    
m_signal = createSignal();
```

with

```
import vibe.core.sync;

    ...

private:
    ManualEvent m_signal;
    
    ...
    
m_signal = createManualEvent();
```

---

#### My Question

I can't find a proper way to port the following snippet

```
m_signal.release();
```

to the my current versions of [dmd](/questions/tagged/dmd) and [vibe](/questions/tagged/vibe).

I suspect that I should drop it given the breaking changes applied but I am not quite sure of my assumption.

**What should I do?**

*More questions to come! I prefer FTB to serialize them by tackling one by one the issues I came across.*

---

#### Details about my Box

- Windows 32 bits
- DMD v2.065
- DUB v0.9.22